# How do I check if MongoDB result is empty in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

```php
$cursor = $collection->find(/*...*/);

if (empty($cursor)) {
    echo "List is empty!";
} else {
    foreach ($cursor as $products) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, `empty` doesn't work on MongoDB results.

Comment: Maybe use [toArray()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/mongodb-driver-cursor.toarray.php), then you can check the size of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we can use the `isDead()` method of the cursor

```php
if (!$products->isDead()) {
    // there are some results
}
```

See the relevant documentation on the [PHP driver docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-cursor.isdead.php)

Answer (score 1):

I don't use MongoDB so I have updated based on the comment.  Use `$collection->count()`.

Check if it evaluates to a *falsey* value:

```
if(!$collection->count()) {
```

Or check for `0`:

```
if($collection->count() == 0) {
```

Or you could check `empty`:

```
if(empty($collection->count())) {
```

Comment: I thought count() was deleted from mongodb cursor

Comment: @AlaaMorad Edited... Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

`$cursor` is an object so it will always evaluate to true

and there is no `$cursor->count()` in PHP driver for mongodb

Note that PHP driver for Mongodb is different from other drivers.

Try this:

```
if ($collection->count(...)) {
   // note you must pass the query to the count function
   $cursor = $collection->find(...);
   foreach ($cursor as $products) {

   }
} else {
    echo "List is empty!";
}
```

OR:

```
$cursor = $collection->find(...);

if (!count($cursor->toarray())) { // convert to array and count it 

    echo "List is empty!";
} else {

    foreach ($cursor as $products) {
    }
}
```